# Qt: How to prevent some of the widgets from getting scrollbars

Tags: qt, layout

I have the following widget layout:

```
HBox
 - VBox
    - HBox
        widget "A"
        widget "B"
    - widget "C"
 - widget "D"
```

In other words, I have something like this:

```
+-----+--------------+
|  A  |              |
+-----+       C      |
|  B  |              |
+-----+--------------+
|         D          |
+--------------------+
```

Depending on the content, "A" and "B" need to expand and consume as much vertical space as is necessary without showing any scrollbars. "D" can contract as necessary.

I tried setting the sizePolicy() of "A" and "B" to be "Minimum" and implemented a sizeHint() for "A" and "B" depending on what they are displaying. However, I still see scrollbars in "A" and "B" while "D" has more space than it needs.

I also tried "minimumExpanding" for the sizePolicy(), but I still keep seeing scrollbars.

How do I make sure that if space is available, "A" and "B" get preferential treatment so that scrollbars are avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [`minimumHeight`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#minimumHeight-prop) and [`minimumWidth`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#minimumWidth-prop) properties of A and B to the lowest possible value where there are no scrollbars. They will still be able to expand but won't shrink below that size.

[Edit:]
After re-reading your question I realized your content of A and B don't always have the same size. Obviously the approach above would only be possible if you know the size of the content whenever it changes. You can just call [`setMinimumHeight()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#minimumHeight-prop)/[`setMinimumWidth()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#minimumWidth-prop) or equally [`setMinimumSize()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) from your code in this case.

Comment: I tried almost exactly what you suggested, i.e., after I figure out how much height is required, set it as the minimum height. However, it just doesn't seem to work. I'll try to see if I can put in a minimal example and post it here.

Comment: I uncovered the problem when I was trying to put together a minimal example. It turns out that there was a widget (deep within "D") which was itself setting its own minimumHeight.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Expanding` as size policy for `A` and `B`. For widget 'D' you should resize it every time the contents of `A` and/or `B` change. It's size policy should be minimum and you should use the `setMinimumHeight`.

If a widget has scrollbars then it should inherit from the [`QAbstractScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractscrollarea.html). You could use the [`setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) and the [`setVerticalScrollBarPolicy`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy-prop) in order to disable scrollbars:

```
A->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
B->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Comment: It feels somehow wrong to have to set the size of "D" when the size of "A" and/or "B" change. This introduces an unnecessary dependency between "A" and "D". If I later change from "D" to some other widget, I'll have to modify the code. I'll give it a shot though.

It would be nice if I could have just set a size policy on A/B.